# Set Display visibility in LWJGL

Tags: java, swing, lwjgl

In LWJGL 2, is there a way to set the display visibility? Similar to how you can call setVisible on a JFrame to show or hide the window. Basically what I want to do is create the OpenGL context using Display.create(), then show a loading splash screen while all my resources are loaded (requires context to be created) and then make the display visible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could parent the display in a Canvas object you create, via Display.setParent.
Then any changes to the parent's visibility will be reflected in the display object.

Otherwise couldn't you just make the splash screen in the context itself, and just switch what you're rendering when ready?

Comment: Thanks! I went with the setParent approach. The reason I didn't want to draw the loading screen inside the window was that I wanted it to be it's own borderless window that contains ONLY the loading image, then show the actual game window.