# Hide created display in LWJGL 2

Tags: java, lwjgl

I am using LWJGL 2 to develop a game. Since I've already written a lot of code with LWJGL 2, I do not consider switching to LWJGL 3.

When starting my game it takes a while to load the textures. During this process, I would like to hide the LWJGL window and show it when all resources have been loaded. But loading the textures requires a display to be created. So my question is:

**Is there a way to hide an already created LWJGL 2 display?**

Thanks in advance

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30136198/set-display-visibility-in-lwjgl) help?

Comment: As far as I understand, this would require me to use a canvas as a parent of the display. I will take a look at it but I think that this would also break some of my code and require me to rewrite the display logic.

Comment: I suggest you upgrade it to LWJGL 3 at least for my taste it is much better i.e. cleaner and leaner. The display helper class was kinda weird anyway. In LWJGL 3 there is `glfwHideWindow()`and `glfwShowWindow()`.